# How to add line breaks for Python code that VS Code Intellisense will use

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

There are similar questions for C# but this one is specifically about the Python Intellisense.

This text:

```
"""Create a Zendesk ticket with the given information.
    * The `description` is ???
    * The `body` is ???
    * Assigned_id values can be found in the settings/base.py file, use this very sparinglingly because
    people take vacations.  If in doubt, leave it out."""
```

Will produce:
[image: Screenshot]

But is there any way to do this without the `*`? Is there a less visible way to add line breaks to docstrings that will translate into Intellisense without becoming one continuous line of text like this?

```
"""Create a Zendesk ticket with the given information.
    The `description` is ???
    The `body` is ???
    Assigned_id values can be found in the settings/base.py file, use this very sparinglingly because
    people take vacations.  If in doubt, leave it out."""
```

Will produce Intellisense that looks like this:

[image: wrapped text screenshot]

Comment: It seems to be interpreting in a markdown-y way, so add a blank line between?

Comment: That burns a lot of screen real-estate in the editor (not the tooltip).  Was hoping for something less intrusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Method one

Use `\n` newline at the end of a sentence

```py
    """Create a Zendesk ticket with the given information. \n
    The `description` is ??? \n
    The `body` is ??? \n
    Assigned_id values can be found in the settings/base.py file, use this very sparinglingly because
    people take vacations.  If in doubt, leave it out."""
```

[image]

##### Method two

Add spaces at the beginning of the sentence

```
    """Create a Zendesk ticket with the given information.
      The `description` is ???
        The `body` is ???
      Assigned_id values can be found in the settings/base.py file, use this very sparinglingly because
    people take vacations.  If in doubt, leave it out."""
```

[image]

##### Method three

Add a blank line between every two lines (*can be used in conjunction with method two*)

```
    """Create a Zendesk ticket with the given information.
     The `description` is ???
    The `body` is ???

    Assigned_id values can be found in the settings/base.py file, use this very sparinglingly because
    people take vacations.  If in doubt, leave it out."""
```

[image]

Comment: Method One for the win, Method Two requires varying the number of spaces at the start of the line (or it just doesn't work at all)
Method Three eats up screen real estate (wasted lines inside a docstring)

Thanks!